# Adding Google-play-services crashes aapt.exe

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services, aapt

I'm trying to use google maps v2 for android by adding the google-play-services to my app as a library. Everytime I set a reference to the library I get windows dialog with the message that aapt.exe has crashed. And after I've set a reference to the library all my source files get errors. R.java in my gen folder gets deleted.
Console is giving this message

`[google-play-services_lib] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!`

After deleting the reference to the google-play-services library the errors disappear. I'm using Eclipse Helio with SDK tools rev 22.0.1

[I tried almost every solution/suggestion people have told in that thread.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21031)

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Do you also have the Android SDK Build-tools package? It's new, not the same as Platform-tools package. Maybe that has something to do with it...

Comment: Yeah I have both. So you suggest to delete build-tools?

Comment: No, do not delete build tools. How are you referencing the Google Play Services in your project?

Comment: I've imported the library in my ecplise workingspace. Then on my actuall app I've done right click > properties > android > Add google play services. Then pressing ok library updates and then I'm getting the errors

Comment: If you haven't yet (but you probably have), maybe try Project > Clean on both of them. Otherwise I would try removing the Google Play Services project and importing it again.

Comment: I already did this multiple times and download other copy of Google Play Services and imported it again. Other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

After you add the Google-play-services_lib to your project using eclipse project properties, you go to view project.properties file in your project folder ( a simple text file that you can edit). Check if the 
**android.library.reference.1**="**your Google-play-services_lib path**" is correct.
You don't need to copy Google-play-services_lib folder to your project like in Google instruction, but the path in project.properties should be correct. I prefer full path like "***c:\android-sdk...***" .
Eclipse creates a relative path which is wrong. It worked for me after I corrected the path.

Comment: Long Live Man! Solved my prob. Gave Absolute Path and hoooha

Answer (score 0):

I realize it's 18 months later now. I couldn't get google-play-services_lib to work as a lib projecte in the Android tab in project settings. But importing it as an Android project and referencing it as a project (in the "projects" tab in Java Build Path) did work.